# Changing Decimal Field Precision in Access Query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to change multiply an access decimal field by 60 (Converting from hours to minutes). However, the decimal field precision is set to 4. Some of the values are larger than 4 digits so Access is giving an error that says 'The decimal field's precision is too small to accept the numeric you attempted to add'.

Right now I have,

```
CLng([Table].[HOURS]*60)
```

The process needs to be automated, preferably without using VBA code. Is there a way to change the precision of the datatype in a query?

Answer (score 0):

If the max. integer value of the field is 9999, and your hour count can exceed 416, you will have to modify the field of the table.